# Deformation of the grid with the falloff

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to model a deformation of a grid with interpollation in the Animation Node, but as you can see I didn't can to use FALLOFF for to get a grid according with 1/r². Can someone help me? is it possible to use an configuration(Falloff) in AN to deform the grid according to the equation [image](-1/r²)?

Equation [-1/(x²+y²)]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mysu3.png)

Comment: Do you want to use Python to construct the falloff. Because I don't think Animation Nodes allow the creation of custom falloff evaluators using native nodes.

Comment: Anything ^^. I have seen in that [link] (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87390/how-to-change-a-mesh-given-by-mathematical-function-with-time-i-e-how-to-includ) that you model equations through AN. I still do not quite understand the math of visual programming. I realized that you have intimacy with the math of the AN. If you can help me, I'll be grateful.

Comment: So you are just looking for a way to visualize this equation using AN? Is there a reason why you can't do it as I explained in the answer you linked?

Comment: I will try. The falloff allows a dynamic with the grid, that is, the movement of the empty in the space deforming the grid, while the modeling of the mesh in the other link is static. What I need is to link an object to mesh and as the object moves in space the mesh becomes deformed. Like this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=segQy1UKV6U

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falloffs in Animation Nodes are mostly hard-coded, that is, you need to write cython/python code to create a custom falloff. So it is much easier to compute the effect you are after manually. A simple implementation of grid deformation is as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Want to transform it based on an empty? Simply subtract the location of the empty from the x and y of your equations:

[image: Result]

Want to scale it? Similarly multiply the scale of the empty to the x and y of the equation.

Comment: Incredible Omar. Thank you again.  I followed his work on squircleart. Want to go back with squircleart?

Comment: @wishmasteregl I took down the site. And probably won't bring it back. However, all of the information that was there is/will be available in Stackexchange, official documentations, and Wikipedia. So no information was lost in the process. Let me know if you need anything.